# Autofac configuration for hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, hangfire, hangfire-autofac

I want to use hangfire in my Asp.Net MVC App and I'm using Autofac as DI.
I've installed Hangfire.Autofac nuget
I want to add a recurring job like this:

---

**UserService.cs**

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public void MyRecurringJob() { // do something here }
}
```

---

**startup.cs**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyApp.Web.Startup))]
namespace MyApp.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var AutofacContainer = AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.ApplicationContainer;
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("AppDbContext").UseAutofacActivator(AutofacContainer);

            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/jobs");
            app.UseHangfireServer();

            var _user = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserService>();
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("SyncUsers", () => _user.MyRecurringJob(), Cron.Hourly());
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Unable to resolve the type 'MyApp.Core.Service.UserService' because the lifetime scope it belongs in can't be located. The following services are exposed by this registration: - MyApp.Core.Service.UserService Details

Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: Unable to resolve the type 'MyApp.Core.Service.UserService' because the lifetime scope it belongs in can't be located. The following services are exposed by this registration:
- MyApp.Core.Service.UserService

Details ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: No scope with a tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.

If you see this during execution of a web application, it generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario). Under the web integration always request dependencies from the dependency resolver or the request lifetime scope, never from the container itself.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test it now, but in order to register a recurring job with Hangfire and Autofac you should write

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<UserService>("SyncUsers", (user) => user.MyRecurringJob(), Cron.Hourly());
```